# How can I find the point where transaction ends in spring integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions

Ok, I added my spring xml configuration for more explaination for my situation.

First, I aggregated 7 channels 
Second, The aggregator releases the aggregated channel declared as a publish-channel.
Thirds, Each 7 subscribe-channels to select indoor-database to make each message.
Forth, Each channel insert data to the external database using jdbc-outbound-channel adaptor.

Below I attached every xml configration related.. Thanks.

```
<int:bridge input-channel="request-write-to-openPMSQueueChannel"
        output-channel="writetoOpenPMSChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000" max-messages-per-poll="-1">
            <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED"
                transaction-manager="transactionExternalDatabaseManager" />
        </int:poller>
    </int:bridge>
```

```
<int:chain input-channel="writetoOpenPMSChannel"
    output-channel="writetoOpenPMS007Channel">
    <int:service-activator method="exectue007">
        <bean id=""
            class="com.sds.redca.core.module.analyzer.convert.ModelingConvertSVC">
        </bean>
    </int:service-activator>
    <int:splitter ref="fromListToRowSplitter" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="writetoOpenPMSChannel"
        output-channel="writetoOpenPMS006Channel">
        <int:service-activator method="exectue006">
            <bean id=""
                class="com.sds.redca.core.module.analyzer.convert.ModelingConvertSVC">
            </bean>
        </int:service-activator>
        <int:splitter ref="fromListToRowSplitter" />
    </int:chain>
```

```
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="writetoOpenPMS001Channel" 
query="INSERT INTO IF_RSRC
       (PJT_ID, DT_INPUT, RSRC_ID, RSRC_TYPE_ID, RSRC_DETAILTYPE_ID, RSRC_NM, CNFG_PJT_NM, RSRC_PATH_NM, LST_RGSTR_ID, LST_RGST_DTM, FINAL_RVSN_NO, YN_USE)
       VALUES
       (:payload[PJT_ID], :headers[timeStamp], :payload[RSRC_ID], :payload[RSRC_TYPE_ID], :payload[RSRC_DETAILTYPE_ID], :payload[RSRC_NM], :payload[CNFG_PJT_NM],
       :payload[RSRC_PATH_NM], :payload[LST_RGSTR_ID], :payload[LST_RGST_DTM], :payload[FINAL_RVSN_NO], :payload[YN_USE])"
data-source="outboundDataSource" />
<int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter channel="writetoOpenPMS002Channel" 
query="INSERT INTO IF_RSRC_RELATION
       (PJT_ID, DT_INPUT, MAIN_RSRC_ID, SUB_RSRC_ID, RELATION_TYPE_CODE_ID)
       VALUES
       (:payload[PJT_ID], :headers[timeStamp], :payload[MAIN_RSRC_ID], :payload[SUB_RSRC_ID], :payload[RELATION_TYPE_CODE_ID])"
data-source="outboundDataSource" />
```

But The problem is that I have to trigger some event right after when 7 insert jobs finish successfully.
How can I get the point where 7 insert transactions finished for triggering some post-event?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not enough info. We need to see the upstream config.

If all your `INSERT`s are in the same TX, you can just and one more subscriber in he end of bussiness logic.

If everything is done withing the same Thread with TX, the TX won't be finished until you don't do that final notification.

From other side, if all of them are live within different transactions you need something like `receipt`, when each item adds some info to one more table to confirm that it has done original work. Yes, it can be at the same TX.

To determine that all desired items finished their work you need to `poll` with short interval that new table with specific business key to count them.

From other side all your tasks can send the same message to the common `<aggregator>` and that one will release a single group for them only when all have committed their transaction.

There might be anoher solution, but we need to know more about your use-case.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the config.

I hope your `writetoOpenPMSChannel` is single-threaded publish-subscribe channel.

So, all your `writetoOpenPMS*` processes are bounded to that poller's TX and will be done one by one within that single TX.

Hence there is no stops to add one more subscriber to that channel as last one. And it receives the same message in the end of TX, just before commit. If you don't have any deferred constraints on those tables everything will be OK and within the single TX.

From other side `<poller>`'s `<transactional>` has `synchronization-factory` option to get deal with commit/rollback using `TransactionSynchronization` strategy: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization

Comment: Like you said, I added my upstream config. please help me. Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Updated an asnwer according to your config.

Comment: Thanks you for your detail reply. But,, still,, I can't know where I can the put post event code. Can you give some more elaborate explanation?

Comment: I tried changing jdbc-outbound-adaptor to jdbc-gate-way for using the reply channel. So, I thought I will aggregator 7 reply channels and I will call post event. but the problem is.. jdbc-gate-way called so many times as the rows inserted.

Comment: You have already several `<int:chain input-channel="writetoOpenPMSChannel">`. What is the problem to add one more in the end of config? This one will accept the request message only in the end after all those adapters will have done their inserts.

Comment: but all those outbound-apdator don't have response-channel. And the chain part you mentioned is for selecting the data and have to be located in front of outbound-adaptor. Sorry for having many questions.

Comment: Don't worry that OK. All your `<chain>`s are one-way and they end up with several inserts according to the `<splitter>`. Sincer evrything is within single thread, the last subscriber will be invoked only after all previous work.

Comment: I can put a post service in the end of one of chains? is it right? Because the post service is to execute every data from every chains at one time.

Comment: M-m-m. You should make each `writetoOpenPMS*` as publish-subscriber too to add that service as the second subscriber.

Comment: But If I make the service times as many as the  count of writeOpenPMS* in the end of chains, the business logic are duplicated.  It is the only way to solve?

Comment: You can `<bridge>` all them to the same `<service-activator>` for that postpocess.